# Pagination won't go to page 2

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I've created a page which uses posts 2 posts and pagination

The pagination will not go to page 2, every time I click the link it reloads the page, however hovering over the page two link shows the correct url(/page/2)

```
$args=array(
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'post_type'         => 'products',
        'connected_type'    => 'product_to_category',
        'connected_items'   => $post,
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'order_by'          => 'menu-order',
        'posts_per_page'    => '10',
        'paged'             => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);


endwhile; endif;
                /* PageNavi at Bottom */
                if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){wp_pagenavi();}
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = $temp;
                wp_reset_query();
```

Custom post type

```
register_post_type('category',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Categories'),
            'singular_name' => __('Category'),
            '_builtin' =>  false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'
        )
    )
);
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Your first code quote is a bit messed up or you simply haven't posted the whole of it. You should look into [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) examples in the WordPress Codex.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the first part of the while but